Continuity question on compact and connected domain
Let $\Omega$ be an open and bounded connected domain from $\mathbb{R}^N$. Consider a continuous function $f:\overline{\Omega}\to\mathbb{R}$. So $K=\overline{\Omega}$ is compact.
My question is: Can we find some $\delta>0$ such that $\forall\ x,y\in K$ with $|x-y|<\delta$ and $f(x)<0<f(y)$ there exists some $z\in K$ with $f(z)=0$ and $|x-z|\leq |x-y|$?
P.S. If $K$ is convex it is clearly true and easy to prove.

No.
Define $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$\Omega = \left\{ (u, v) \in (0, 1) \times \mathbb{R} : \left| v - \sin \frac{\pi}{u} \right| < \frac{1}{10} \right\}$$
and $f : \overline{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(u, v) = \begin{cases} u \cos \frac{\pi}{u} & \text{if } u > 0, \\ 0 & \text{if } u = 0. \end{cases}$$
Clearly $\Omega$ is open, bounded and connected and $f$ is continuous. But the property in question fails: given any $\delta > 0$, pick $x = \left( \frac{1}{2n-1}, 0 \right)$ and $y = \left( \frac{1}{2n}, 0 \right)$ with $n$ sufficiently large, so that $|x-y| < \delta$. The only sensible candidates for $z$ are $(0, 0)$ and $\left( \frac{1}{2n-\frac{1}{2}}, -\frac{9}{10} \right)$, both clearly too far from $x$.


Thank you. I forgot to specify that the interior of $K$ shall be non empty. Sorry about that...

You can just attach a closed disc anywhere and the counterexample will still work.

@Bogdan I've updated the counterexample.

Thank you very much. I have also edited my post to make it clearer. My mistake, again.

@Bogdan I guess the example still works if you "thicken" every circle keeping them disjoint. But it may take me a while to make an appropriate edit. I hope this is the final version of the question though?

Yes, it is the final version. Sorry, again and thank you so much for your interest!

That looks awesome! Thank you very much!
